# Add a digit to every contact

Tags: contacts, automation, google-contacts

My city is adding a new digit to its number to increase the number of combinations possible. I have over 300 contacts, editing them manually is not really a good way to do that.

98% of my contacts is on the + XX ( country code ) + XX ( state code ) + XXXXXXXX ( the number ) format.

I need to add the digit 9 to every number, so after running a program script whatever every contact should be +XX XX 9XXXXXXXX .

Bonus : I have contacts from people of other cities who must stay the same if possible I would like a solution like this : if state number is XX then skip it. But is better to manually change this group of contacts than all the contacts from my city so it's OK if that's not possible

Answer (score 3):

Only thing that I can think of is:

- Go to the web interface for Google contacts, click on export (it should redirect to the older version of contacts)
- In the older interface click on 'other' (or something similar) near the icon to add contacts
- You will see the voice 'export'. Click on it
- Choose the group 'personal contacts' (should include only the contacts from the address book of your phone)
- Then choose 'format CSV for Google' as the export format
- Open this file (Excel, Calc or similar will do) and use the function 'find and replace' this way:

  Search for the two digit that identify the city and replace them with XX9. Pay attention to the numbers which include these two digits in other places. You may want to edit them manually and the rest with find-replace. (There may be even easier ways to do it, but I'm not very good with Excel.)
- Once you are done, go back to the web interface and this time choose import and the file you edited as the file to import.

This should help.

Comment: Thanks so much ! But I don't have access to any PC right now , can I do this on phone ?

Comment: Yes you can, I think with any app that opens excel files, it just needs to have 'find and replace'. For sure with the one by Google you can, but it may be a little bit frustrating. Anyway, to access the web interface open any browser on your phone and go to contacts.google.com